# Mouse events on shape in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm working on project similar to: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182683/NetworkView-A-WPF-custom-control-for-visualizing-a. 
I bind connection to Arrow class, which derives Shape this way:

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConnectionViewModel}">
  <local:Arrow Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" Fill="Black" Start="{Binding SourceConnectorHotspot}" End="{Binding DestConnectorHotspot}" IsHitTestVisible="False" MouseEnter="Arrow_MouseEnter"  MouseDown="Arrow_MouseDown"/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Is there any way to add doubleClick event or any kind of mouse related events to that arrow?

Comment: `Shape` derives from `FrameworkElement` which also derives from `UIElement`. `UIElement` supports many events for interaction so `Shape` can be used as any control in term of user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

I can't belive it. I wasted so much time and found an answer 15minutes afted posting question. I copied code above. It turns out that this line of code:

```
IsHitTestVisible="False"
```

"turns of" events.